# Is it possible to have a pluralised StringArray? Android

Tags: java, android, localization

I'm creating an Android app in Java

I have a `Spinner` that with have the following entries using a StringArray resource:
'day', 'week', 'month' and 'year'
i also have an `EditText` where i can enter a number to chose the amount of days/weeks ect
so I could set:

1 week,
4 year,
8 day
ect

I would like to switch the spinner to a pluralised version of the string array and then use the provided number as the quantity, so the above would be more grammatically correct.

Is there a 'proper' way to do this? Hopefully something like `getResources().getQuantityStringS(...)` or something?

Comment: You have to notify the adapter after changing the dataset . In this case may set a new Adapter because you must be using `ArrayAdapter` .And i don't think you can make a String array pluralized so you have to have 2 array or just have each item as String and then build the array from code .

Comment: @ADM Yeah, i've just decided to go down the 2 array route for now, in lieu of a better solution. Not ideal cus it won't handle localization of different quantities automatically, but yeah looks like its the best i've got